# Related videos at the end of youtube embed

Tags: api, youtube

So we already know [YouTube has changed the way `rel` parameter works](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018), so there is no way not to show related videos anymore. So I wonder how come in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpcto531/) the first video DOES relate to the `rel` parameter, and the second one doesn't.

Anyone can explain?

Comment: Can't notice any difference. Did you try in incognito mode? Youtube personalizes it if you're logged in.

Comment: I think because the player size is too small to show video suggestion thumbnails, try to increase the width and height of the player.